# UIImage distorted when using it for UIImageView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I have taken a photo, and then I'm initializing a UIImageView object with this photo. The only problem is, when I take the photo, the photo is being taken using the full iPhone screen (portrait).

The UIImageView that is being initialized with this photo is only set to take up the top 50% of the iphone's screen. So you can imagine the image looks distorted.

I have been able to make it look a lot better by using the following code:

```
UIImageView *halfView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:image];

[self.view addSubview:halfView];

halfView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height/2);

halfView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
```

The only problem is, the final UIImageView called "halfView" is still slightly distorted.

I have a feeling that this is impossible to fix, because the original photo is being taken with the full iphone screen and can never perfectly scale to fit a UIImageView that only takes up the top 50% of the iphone screen.

I was basically trying to copy the frontback app. Here is what it looks like when you are taking the original image in their app:

[image]

This is what my app's screen looks like when you are taking the picture:

[image]

And then right after you take the picture, my app's screen changes to look like the frontback screen and takes the picture you just took and places it in the top half and tries to scale it.

I hope that makes sense. I know it is a long question, but I just really wanted to let the user use the full screen while taking the photo and then just scale it to half the screen.

Am I going about this all wrong? Am I crazy to think I could ever properly scale the image to half the screen when it was originally captured as a "full screen" image?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: possible that your imageview size getting increased by using ios 7? check height of your imageview is same as you assined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of argument let's say your captured image size is 640x1136 (twice the size of an iPhone 5 screen) and you are trying to display it in a `UIImageView` with of size 320x284 (half the size of an iPhone 5 screen). 
As you can already see from these dimensions the captured image's width is smaller than its height whereas the `UIImageView`'s width is larger than its height - the proportions are different.

Therefore, scaling the captured image to fit the `UIImageView`'s width (scale by 0.5) means the captured image will be of size 320x568 - its height is larger than the `UIImageView`'s height. 
Scaling the captured image to fit the `UIImageView`'s height (scale by 0.25) means the captured image will be of size 160x284 - its width is smaller the the `UIImageView`'s width.

The image can't scale exactly like you want it to scale. However, you can use `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill` to fill the entire `UIImageView` but lose some of the image (image's height is too big to fit). You can also choose to use `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` which will show the entire image but will leave some space on the sides (image's width is too small).

Another option you have is to actually capture the image in the proportions of your `UIImageView` in the first place but that means you won't be able to capture a full screen image.

Comment: I knew it didn't make sense.. I really don't know what I was expecting. It will never be able to scale like that perfectly. The only option is to capture the original image in the half screen size. Thanks for the help Gad.

Answer (score 1):

Try this function, pass your `UIImage` in this function along with the new `size`, in turn it will return you the `UIImage` with size specified by you.

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

I guess this is what you want.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to objective-c and confused how I would actually enter in your code? The "+" sign is what's confusing me. It looks like a method implementation to me but I'm used to doing "-(void)methodName".

Comment: Do I need to put "+ (UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize;" in the View Controller's interface area, and then paste your full code in the implementation area?

Comment: ya...in my project I wanted this method to be a class method, you can use "-" instead of "+".

Comment: check the updated answer and let me know whether this works for you or not.

Comment: if you are accessing this method inside the same controller then you don't need to put it in interface area. But if you want to access this method from some other class or view controller then you need to declare in .h file interface.

Comment: Sorry I'm lost. I put this in my VC's interface area "-(UIImage *)imageWithImage:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize;" and then your full code in the implementation area. It doesn't like the "imageWithImage" identifier and says that the method definitions can't be found.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47721/discussion-between-user3117509-and-prashant-n)

Comment: Hi, I took the statement out of the interface and now there is only 1 error left. It's saying "use of undeclared identifier 'imageWithImage' "

Comment: Prashant if you can give me 1min in chat ill pick your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You mention the image takes up the full size of the screen. If it's to display the UIImageView taking up half the screen, then you'll need to add this code to clip the frame

```
halfView.clipToBounds = YES;
```

Despite making the size of the imageview half the screen, the actual image will show outside the boundaries of the imageview if it's original size is bigger with the aspectFit property. clipToBounds will fix this.

I hope this is what you're looking for. Thanks, Jim.

Comment: Thanks for the help Jim, but your code did not help. The only realistic solution is the one Gad offered below.